# Xfinium multiline cell with different fonts

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin

Is there a possibility in Xfinium to draw a table with a multiline cell with different fonts normal/italic like in the example below

[image: table example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be implemented. The cells are PdfFlowTableCompositeCell objects and you set their content with PdfFlowTextContebt objects. The PdfFlowTextContebt lets you draw formatted text, you can have the first line regular and the second in italic.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library.